# display row data as column in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I have a DB table with below structure in **SQLITE**

```
Name        Count          Type
Roy          3              CA
Roy          2              BT
John         2              CA
John         1              BT
```

Need a query that can display the above data like below(sqlite)

```
Name         count        CA       BT   
Roy            5           3        2
John           3           2        1
```

thanks

Comment: Are the possible values for Type known in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no pivoting in SQLite, but you can use a lot of subquerys:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name,
    (SELECT sum([count]) FROM test tst WHERE tst.name = test.name) as count,
    (SELECT sum([count]) FROM test tst WHERE tst.name = test.name AND type='CA') as CA,
    (SELECT sum([count]) FROM test tst WHERE tst.name = test.name AND type='BT') as BT
    FROM test
```

assuming tablename "test"